# Get Aggregate Count of Column After Group by in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not a strong database person but i have an intermediate knowledge of it. Here is my challenge which I'm facing, I have a table like -

```
pin  type   day month year timestamp value
---- -----  --- ---   ---  --------  -----
123  clicks 02  12    2014 unixtime  3
123  clicks 03  12    2014 unixtime  7
111  clicks 02  12    2014 unixtime  10
```

I would like a mysql query that would select all rows that the `pin=$pin and month=$month` and return all columns with an aggregate count of the `value`

For the sample dataset above , id like to get something like

```
pin  type   month year  timestamp value
---- -----  ---   ---   ---       --------  -----
123  clicks 12    2014  unixtime  10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use GROUP BY, SUM() and COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT(month) as month, SUM(value) AS value
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE pin = '$pin'
AND month='$month' // Added $month in condition
GROUP BY pin, month, year // Added some conditions
```

**Explanation:**

You need

1) all rows of `pin` specified so, used `WHERE`

2) COUNT of month for the specified `pin` so used, `COUNT()`

3) SUM of value for the specified `pin` so used, `SUM()`

Comment: Sorry for the question - do i also add the `month=$month` in the where clause?
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just for the record, there's a typo (extra "and" in "AND and month='$month'")

Comment: @KonstantinosFilios, I am really thankful to you. typo corrected.

Comment: FYI putting variables direct into a query like this opens it up to SQL injection. You should use binding. Just in case someone else comes across this answer for help

Answer (score 0):

This could be done as

```
select
pin,
type,
day,
month,
year,
timestamp,
sum(value) as value 
from table_name
where pin='$pin' and month='$month'
group by pin,month,year
```

If you do not want the grouping per month then remove it from group by clause and use only year.

**Note that the above query is mysql specific. In standard when you select some columns using aggregate function they must appear in he `group by` clause.**